# Is it possible to write 'with queries' in jpa specifications

Tags: java, jpa, specifications, nativequery

I have native query written with 'with queries'. How could it be rewritten by jpa specifications? It's the small part of code

```
with sub_query1 as (
    select table1.id
    from table1
    join table2 ON table1.id = table2.contract_id
    where table2.administrator_id = 11
    order by table1.create_date desc
), sub_query2 as (
    select table1.id
    from table1
    join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
    where table3.administrator_id = 11
    order by table1.create_date desc
)
select table1.id
from table1    
where (table1.id in (select id from esa_subquery) or table1.id in (select id from ec_subquery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a `table1` entity, a `table2` entity with `contract` and `administrator` relations and a table3 with `administrator` relation, you can rewrite it like that

```
select t from table1 where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.contract.id = t.id and t2.administrator.id = 11) or exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.id = t1.id and t3.administrator.id = 11)
```

Comment: actually I meant to rewrite sub_query1 and sub_query2 with jpa specifications, such as criteriaBuilder and etc. And to use results of this query in where statement

Comment: something like query.subquery()

Comment: criteriaBuilder deals also  with "exists" statement : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-exists-method.html